# Tailwind css not extended

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I'm trying to extend my tailwind css by adding the following to the config:

```
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        'regal-blue': '#243c5a',
      },
      backgroundColor: {
        'bg-r-c': 'rgba(144, 44, 20, 1)',
        'bg-b-c': 'rgba(38, 70, 83, 1)',
        'bg-b2-c': 'rgba(42, 157, 143, 1)',
        'bg-beige-c': 'rgba(233, 199, 114, 1)',
        'bg-beige2-c': 'rgba(244, 162, 97, 1)'
        } 
     },
  },
```

Even tho I just copied it from the docs it's not working. Any idea how to add the (background)colors?

Comment: How do you compile it? Do you use Tailwind CLI, Webpack, Vite or something else? Did you restart that _bundling tool_?

Comment: I'm using vite @Jax-p
Also restarted it several times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the [documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/background-color) correctly, `backgroundColor` in `extend` section is only used for adding states (like *active* which is in example).

If you would like to extend it via the default palette you can place it to the `theme` (without `extend`) and spread the default values via JavaScript:

```js
theme: {
  backgroundColor: theme => ({
      ...theme('colors'), // this will insert default colors palette
      'primary': '#3490dc',
      'secondary': '#ffed4a',
      'danger': '#e3342f',
  })
}
```

---

Mainly **you should use the color palette** (not backgroundColor palette).

> By default, Tailwind makes the entire default **color palette** available as background colors.
>
> source: [Tailwind CSS | Background Color customizing](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/background-color#customizing)

```
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        'regal-blue': '#243c5a',
        'r-c': 'rgba(144, 44, 20, 1)', // generates .bg-r-c
        'b-c': 'rgba(38, 70, 83, 1)', // generates .bg-b-c
        'b2-c': 'rgba(42, 157, 143, 1)',
        'beige-c': 'rgba(233, 199, 114, 1)',
        'beige2-c': 'rgba(244, 162, 97, 1)'
        } 
     },
  },
```

---

If you need explicit classes like `.bg-r-c` and you don't want to have `.text-r-c` (etc.) you might want to write it simply in the CSS file instead of config.